# Adjust the layout when the soft keyboard is on in android

Tags: android, view, android-softkeyboard

I have an activity where the view is like a form, where user can enter the details and At the bottom there are two buttons "save" and "cancel". The form has many number of edit boxes.
So I have taken a relative layout and put all these edit boxes in it and then put the relative layout inside scroll view. I have taken another relative layout to add "Save" and "cancel" button.
    Finally I have put the scroll view and relative layout(which has buttons) in another relative layout which is the main view of my activity.

My problem is , when I click any of the edit box, keyboard will come up and it hides the buttons(Save and Cancel).

I want to make the buttons to display above the keyboard(When the keyboard is on) like  in the edit contact activity of "Contacts" Application .

I am using  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" for my activity but of no use.
I have gone through so many stack overflow questions regarding this but I am not able to achieve this.

How can I do this with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Edit Contact activity save button is added to layout in bottom, and outside of scroll view.

What you can do, to make your save and cancel button visible all the time, wheather, soft keyboard is visible, or not. Make parent layout a `relativelayout`, in this layout add two views one scroll view, and other relativelayout having buttons. Let Relative Layout properties `layout_width=fill_parent` and `layout_height=wrap_content`, and `align_parent_bottom=true`, and scroll view's `layout_width=fill_parent`, `layout_height=fill_parent`, `lavout_above=@+id/rlButtons`,  in ScrollView, add a RelativeLayout having all the editTexts.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution .
  My parent layout is Relative Layout . In this layout I added a Scroll View and a relative layout. In the scroll view I added a relative layout which is having all edit texts. In relative layout I added save and cancel buttons. I set the scroll view weight = 1. 
For my activity  I set  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize".